# Как запустить и убить другое приложение из Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

Есть однопоточное приложение-работник - оно запускается с аргументами в командной строке и складывает результаты работы в указанную папку. Также есть приложение-менеджер, оно запускает несколько работников (для использования многопоточности) и в отдельном потоке просматривает папки с результатами их работы.

С запуском приложения-работника проблем нет (использую `CreateProcess`). Как приложением-менеджером "убить" приложение-работника? Другими словами - как из Delphi запустить другое приложение, и в одностороннем порядке его "убить" или приказать ему закрыться?

P.S. Оба приложения написаны мной. Убийство по имени процесса не подойдет, т.к. у всех работников имя одинаковое.

Comment: По-моему, именно "убивать" процесс - плохая идея. Раз оба процесса написаны вами, то лучше организуйте обмен сообщениями между ними (через windows messages, shared memory, pipes, tcp и т.д) и из главного приложения приказывайте дочернему завершиться. И уже в крайнем случае, когда дочернее вдруг откажется реагировать на команды, используйте TerminateProcess.

Comment: @zed вот меня пока интересует максимально нетрудозатратный процесс, т.к. оба приложения утилиты для личного пользования

Comment: приложение-работник это консольное приложение или оконное?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci На данный момент оконное (хотя консольного бы хватило, но переделывать дольше)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вариант с чистым убийством через TerminateProcess:**
Как писали выше это не очень хороший вариант, но может вам больше и не надо, поэтому привожу пример.

```
program KillTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.SyncObjs,
  WinApi.Windows;

procedure DoWork();
begin
  Writeln('Worker');

  while True do begin
    Sleep(500);
  end;
end;

procedure CreateWaitKillWorker(const ExeName: String);
var
  Si: TStartupInfo;
  Pi: TProcessInformation;
  CommandLine: String;
begin
  Writeln('Manager');
  CommandLine := ExeName + ' -C';

  Si := Default(TStartupInfo);
  Si.cb := sizeof(si);

  if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(CommandLine), nil, nil, false, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, nil, nil, Si, Pi) then begin
    try
      Sleep(5000);
      TerminateProcess(Pi.hProcess, 0);
    finally
      CloseHandle(Pi.hProcess);
      CloseHandle(Pi.hThread);
    end;
  end;

  Readln;
end;


var
  ChildProcExeName: String;
begin
  try
    ChildProcExeName := ParamStr(0);

    if ParamCount > 0 then
      DoWork()
    else
      CreateWaitKillWorker(ChildProcExeName);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

**Вариант с вежливым убийством через TEvent:**
Это вариант лучше если вам нужно закрыть дочерний процесс более аккуратно.

```
program KillTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.SyncObjs,
  WinApi.Windows;

procedure DoWork();
var
  Event: TEvent;
begin
  Writeln('Worker');

  Event := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, 'Test');
  try
    while Event.WaitFor(0) = TWaitResult.wrTimeout do begin
      Sleep(2000);
    end;
  finally
    Event.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure CreateWaitKillWorker(const ExeName: String);
var
  Si: TStartupInfo;
  Pi: TProcessInformation;
  CommandLine: String;
  Event: TEvent;
begin
  Writeln('Manager');
  CommandLine := ExeName + ' -C';

  Si := Default(TStartupInfo);
  Si.cb := sizeof(si);

  Event := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, 'Test');
  try
    if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(CommandLine), nil, nil, false, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, nil, nil, Si, Pi) then begin
      try  
        Sleep(5000);
        Event.SetEvent();
        //WaitForSingleObject(Pi.hProcess, INFINITE); // если не обходимо ждать
      finally
        CloseHandle(Pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(Pi.hThread);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Event.Free;
  end;

  Readln;
end;

var
  ChildProcExeName: String;
begin
  try
    ChildProcExeName := ParamStr(0);

    if ParamCount > 0 then
      DoWork()
    else
      CreateWaitKillWorker(ChildProcExeName);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

**PS:** Примеры в консоли, но ни что не мешает их использовать в оконом приложении, правда для окон я предпочел бы вариант который описал [kot-da-vinci](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/857016/186074)

Comment: Сложно выбрать какой ответ лучше. Ответил бы все ответы правильными, но выберу ваш - вам и репа не повредит, и способ с `TerminateProcess` самый простой.

Answer (score 2):

Для аккуратного завершения нужно предусмотреть какой-либо способ межпроцессного взаимодействия (IPC).

Один из простых способов - сообщения Windows

Дли идентификации работника, раз уж командная строка используется, можно в командной строке передавать его идентификатор (уникальное число, в этом примере - `WORKER_ID`)

При необходимости менеджер посылает сообщение

```
PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_STOPMYWORK, 0, WORKER_ID);
```

Чтобы не возиться с поиском окна, здесь используется широковещательное сообщение (всем окнам верхнего уровня), но его использование требует ([часть Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx)) регистрации сообщения в системе (в обеих программах одно и то же имя) с помощью RegisterWindowMessage.

Если окна нет, можно создать невидимое функцией `AllocateHWND`, обеспечив ему функцию - обработчик сообщений (см. исходники `TTimer` в `ExtCtrls.pas`)

Приняв такое сообщение, работник проверяет , что идентификатор его (поле сообщения `M.LParam` совпадает с `WORKER_ID`), и выполняет остановку - если возможно, то сразу, если идёт запись - то выставляет флаг остановки, который нужно проверять по окончанию записи

Тестовый код:

Менеджер:

```
WM_STOPWORK: Integer

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_STOPWORK, 0, 1);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WM_STOPWORK := RegisterWindowMessage('WM_STOPWORK');
end;
```

клиент:

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if (Msg.message = WM_STOPWORK) then begin
    if Msg.LParam = Worker_Id then
      if AState = 1 then
          AFlag := True
      else
          Close;
    Handled := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WM_STOPWORK := RegisterWindowMessage('WM_STOPWORK');
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AState := 1;
  Label1.Caption := 'Working';
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  Sleep(3000);
  if AFlag then
      Close;
  AState := 2;
  Label1.Caption := 'Waiting';
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы корректно закрыть приложение, нужно отправить сообщение `WM_CLOSE` в его главное окно. Чтобы отправить сообщение окну, нужно знать его хэндл. Если вы сами создавали эти процессы, то ID процессов у вас уже есть (`CreateProcess` возвращает его в структуре `_PROCESS_INFORMATION`). Осталось определить хэндл главного окна по ID процесса. Для этого можно воспользоваться функцией [`EnumWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx), которая перебирает все окна верхнего уровня, т.е. главные.

```
type
  TProcessIDsArray = array of Cardinal;

procedure TForm2.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ProcessID: Cardinal;
  ProcessIDs: TProcessIDsArray;
begin
  // для примера возьмем свой собственный ID процесса
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(Application.MainFormHandle, ProcessID);

  // задаем размер массива по количеству имеющихся ID процессов 
  SetLength(ProcessIDs, 1);
  ProcessIDs[0] := ProcessID;

  // указатель на нашу функцию колбэка и параметр (наш массив с ID)
  EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsProc, lParam(ProcessIDs));
end;
```

Сама функция колбэка, уже получив хэндл окна, проверяет принадлежит ли он одному из наших процессов и, если да, отправляет ему сообщение `WM_CLOSE`. Сделаем небольшой хак. Раз уж мы вторым параметром передавали наш список ID, то тип второго параметра в сигнатуре функции колбэка напишем не `lParam`, а `TProcessIDsArray`, поскольку размер этих типов в байтах совпадает.

```
function EnumWindowsProc(WindowHandle: HWND; ProcessIDs: TProcessIDsArray): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  ProcessID: Cardinal;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := True; // будем перебирать все окна

  // получаем ID процесса по хэндлу его главного окна
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(WindowHandle, ProcessID);

  // сравниваем полученный ID с нашим списком
  for i := 0 to Length(ProcessIDs) - 1 do
    if ProcessID = ProcessIDs[i] then
    begin
      // если нашли, отправляем сообщение о закрытии окна
      PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
      Exit;  // перебирать список процессов дальше не имеет смысла
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Если переделаете свои воркеры на консольные приложения, то нужно будет придумывать что-то еще :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать метод межпотоковой синхронизации, расширив его на процессы.

Например через мутексы (Delphi 7):

```
program Runner;

uses
  Windows, SysUtils;

const
  N_MUTEX = 'WRKRN';
var
  Index: Integer;
  Controls: array [0..4] of THandle;
  MutexName: string;
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
begin
  for Index := 0 to 4 do begin
    MutexName := N_MUTEX + IntToStr(Index);
    Controls[Index] := CreateMutex(nil, TRUE, PChar(MutexName));
    FillChar(StartupInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), 0);
    StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
    StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    CreateProcess(
      nil,
      PChar('worker.exe ' + N_MUTEX + IntToStr(Index)),
      nil,
      nil,
      FALSE,
      0,
      nil,
      PChar(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))),
      StartupInfo,
      ProcessInfo);
  end;
  MessageBox(0, 'Press [Enter] to stop workers...', 'Action', MB_APPLMODAL or MB_OK);
  for Index := 0 to 4 do begin
    ReleaseMutex(Controls[Index]);
    CloseHandle(Controls[Index]);
    Sleep(500); { чтобы визуально видеть что работники отключаются по одному }
  end;
end.
```

И процесс-работник:

```
program Worker;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows, SysUtils;

const
  WORK: array [0..3] of Char = ('-', '\', '|', '/');
var
  hMutex: THandle;
  WorkIdx: Integer;
begin
  WorkIdx := 0;
  hMutex := CreateMutex(nil, FALSE, PChar(ParamStr(1)));
  { 250 для замедления работы, в реальном приложении - 0 }
  while WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, 250) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do begin
    Write(#8 + WORK[WorkIdx]);
    Inc(WorkIdx);
    if WorkIdx > 3 then
      WorkIdx := 0;
  end;
  CloseHandle(hMutex);
  WriteLn;
  WriteLn('Worker terminated! Press [Enter] to exit!');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Обработка ошибок и закрытие хэндлов остаётся на самостоятельную работу.

Comment: В реальном приложении цикл с `WaitForSingleObject` надо выносить в отдельный поток и ни в коем случае не передавать 0 в качестве таймаута.

Comment: Чем это продиктовано?

Comment: Соображениями производительности. Когда поток находится внутри `WaitForSingleObject` он не использует процессор, поэтому выныривать из этой функции нужно как можно реже (в качестве таймаута можно вообще указать INFINITE, чтобы управление вернулось только по ожидаемому событию). Если же таймаут равен нулю, то управление возвращается мгновенно и поток будет почём зря греть CPU стопроцентной нагрузкой.

Comment: В данном контексте Wait используется для проверки флага остановки, этот цикл -  аналог: `while not Terminated do SomeWork();`, поэтому там и 0. Тут именно что ожидание не требуется.